# Cannot trigger addListenerForSingleValueEvent

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a piece of code below. I don't know why the onDataChange cannot be triggered. As a result, the object singleChildSummary is null.

```
>ChildSummary singleChildSummary;
>DatabaseReference childSummaryRef = getChildDatabaseReference().child(id);
>     childSummaryRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
>                 @Override
>                 public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
>                     singleChildSummary = dataSnapshot.getValue(ChildSummary.class);
 >                 }
>     
>                 @Override
>                 public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
>                     // Failed to read value
>     //                Log.w(TAG, "Failed to read value.", error.toException());
>                 }
>             });
```

Answer (score 0):

If getValue() returns null "if there is no data at this location", according to the [API documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DataSnapshot.html#getValue(boolean)).

Comment: Is that ok if I use this: singleChildSummary = dataSnapshot.getValue(ChildSummary.class); in the onDataChange event ?

Comment: I don't know, what does your database structure look like at the location you're listening to? What does ChildSummary look like? There's a lot of missing pieces here.  All I can tell you is that null means no data was found at the location.